# $http post no funciona en angularjs por CORS

Tags: angularjs, spring

Estoy trabajand en una aplicación en AngularJS v 1.7 en el front-end y SpringBoot en el back-end, en este último tengo habilitado los cors. pero en angularjs cuando envio una petición de tipo POST lo que envia es un OPTIONS y me devuelve un 200 pero núnca envia el POST.

el codigo para hacer la petición es:

Factory

```
myApp.factory('$loginService', ['$http', '$backendConection', function ($http, $backendConection) {
return {
    login: login     
};

function login(data) {

    return $http({
        url: 'http://' + $backendConection.server_ip + ':' + $backendConection.port + '/auth/signin',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data

    });
}
```

}]);

Controllers

```
$loginService.login({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).then(
            function (response) {
              alert("OK");
            }, function(error){
                alert("Error")
            })
```

Response Headers
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda

Configuracines en Spring boot

```
@Component
```

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

```
public CORSFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

configuración de Spring Security

```
@Component
```

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

```
public CORSFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Spring Security

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/components/**",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Hay algún mensaje en la consola tras el options?

Comment: Si: POST http://10.4.27.213:8080/auth/signin 400

Comment: ¿es necesario poner la configuracion de spring boot? para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Según vi en internet si el response headers es como el que tengo yo pues la configuración del backend esta bien.

Comment: Lo que te falla entonces no es CORS, es el *sign-in*: [HTTP 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) es *Bad Request* (Petición errónea)

Comment: Yo tenia este codigo dentro de la carpata resources en spring boot y funcionaba bien pero al dividir los proyectos back-end y front-end me paso esto, por eso se que el servicio web esta bien.

Comment: bueno en spring boot yo uso un Filter, para devolver ese response headers que esa es la solución que encontre en internet paro en WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter hay que hacer otras configuraciones y me estoy perdiendo un poco

Comment: La consola me da este error:Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.4.27.213:8080/auth/signin' from origin 'http://10.4.27.213' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 0):

AngulasJS a partir de la versión 1.2.x en adelante no tiene problemas con los cors así que todo el problema está en el servidor. Primero hay que habilitarle los cors y eso se hace con la clase CORSFilter como está en el ejemplo, lo que cambie fue una línea de código. Mi solución NO LA CORRECTA pero funcional fue aceptar todos los Headers (*).

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");
```

por

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

La primera no me funcionaba porque no tenía todos los Access-Control-Allow-Headers necesarios. Cuando se hace un CORS este manda un OPTIONS al servidor para comprobar que el dominio que hace la petición tiene permiso, para esto dentro de los parámetros del Response tiene que definirse los Headers que van a necesitar.
Bueno si alguien tiene otra opinión sería bueno que lo comentara ya que soy muy nuevo en todo esto y puedo estar equivocado, gracias.